# Limit question math here please?

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\tan(\pi/4 + ax))}{\sin(bx)}
$$
  where b and a are two coefficients different from zero. I tried L'Hôpital,but nothing..

Comment: How do you mean: 'but nothing..'?

Comment: it is correct :)

Comment: by nothing I mean, the answer should be 2,and I dont get a neat solution ...

Answer (score 1):

I would think that L'Hopital should work for you.
The derivative of the numerator is
$$
\frac{1}{\tan(\pi/4 + ax)}\sec^2(\pi/4 + ax)a.
$$
The derivative of the denominator is
$$
\cos(bx)b
$$.

Ok, so more details:
So by L'Hopitals rule the limit is:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sec^2(\pi/4 + ax)a}{\tan(\pi/4 + ax)\cos(bx)b} = \frac{a\sec^2(\pi/4)}{b\tan(\pi/4)}.
$$
Now all that is left is for you to evaluate this expression.

Comment: I had already done it ,master,and the result was 2a/b but in my book its just 2..i was just joking..thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Since the following holds for $x\to0$

$\displaystyle \sin(bx)\sim bx,\quad \ln\big(\tan(\pi/4+ax)\big)=\ln\bigg(1+\frac{2\tan(ax)}{1-\tan(ax)}\bigg)\sim \frac{2\tan(ax)}{1-\tan(ax)} \sim \frac{2ax}{1-\tan(ax)}$

Hence
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\big(\tan(\pi/4+ax)\big)}{\sin(bx)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2ax}{bx\big(1-\tan(ax)\big)}=\frac{2a}{b}$